# How to execute assembly opcodes without storing it into buffer c/python?

Tags: python, c, cython

Say, I have the following number of OpCode Bytes `\x90\x90\x90\xb8\x05\x00\x00\x00` (Note the length of bytes could differ). I would like to execute these opcodes without having to store it into a buffer, and the reason I don't like it, is because a buffer is stored in data segment of the memory which then you have to provide execute permission to the buffer which may raise security concerns.

Since, we can use c's inline-assembly to execute assembly instruction, I was expecting that below may work:

```
__asm__("db 0x90");
```

but it throws `Error: no such instruction: db 0x90`

Can anyone tell me how do I execute opcodes without storing it into a buffer, I don't mind using either `c` or `python` as I am using cython.

Comment: If working on Windows, you can get the address of the '.text' section of the PE and append these opcodes to the end of the section. But you should make sure that you have enough space in the end of the section. Notice that you also should convert the Relative VAs to VAs.

Comment: You cannot use the pseudo code `db` in inline assembly.

Comment: Did you try to put the buffer variable in the `.text` section? -- What compiler for which target system are you using? You might need to use the correct pseudo instruction name, some assemblers want `.db`, for GCC on x86 it's `.byte`.

Comment: @thebusybee you are so handsome :) it is indeed `.byte` this worked `__asm__(".byte 0xb8;.byte 0x0d; .byte 0x00; .byte 0x00; .byte 0x00; mov %%eax, res":::);printf("%d\n", res);`

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. If you think that my answer fits your issue, please mark it. That's the SO way to say "thank you".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for your assembler requires to use `.byte` instead of `db`.

GCC accepts two different dialects, "att" and "intel". The default is "att", but you can change it with the option `-masm=...`.

The default assembler's documentation can be found with the keywords "gnu binutils", for example the current version knows these [pseudo operations](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.37/as.html#Pseudo-Ops). It also lists the mnemonic `.dc.b` for bytes.